# Accessing deeper array keys

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a navigation menu which supports dropdown items. I have created

```
var menuItems={
items:[
{
    title:"Home",
    id:1
},
{
    title:"Download App",
    children:["iOS","Android","Windows"],
    id:2
},
{
    title:"About",
    id:3
}
]
};
```

This is my Menu Prototype Class:

```
var MenuProto = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return <li><a>{this.props.title}</a>
      <ul className="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a>{this.props.children}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
}
});
```

And this is where it is called:

```
var Menu = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
    var fullmenu = this.props.items.map(function(item){
       return <MenuProto {...item}/>
    });
    return <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       {fullmenu}
    </ul>
  }
});
```

Apparently this.props.children gets all the array and uses renders it on the menu while I need it to get them one by one. I have tried creating a **var** similar to ***fullmenu*** which would iterate through childrens of this.props.children one by one but I can't figure out how.

I would also need a hint on how to make a conditional to see if an object has or doesnt have the ***children*** key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on `this.props.children` using the [`React.Children` utilities](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children):

```js
var MenuProto = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return <li><a>{this.props.title}</a>
      <ul className="dropdown-menu">
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
          return <li key={child.id}><a>{child.title}</a></li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </li>
}
});
```

Since you want to support nested items, you'll need some additional custom logic.

You can check to see if an object has a `children` key by simply testing for the existence of `whatever.children`; if it doesn't have that key, it will be a falsy value (specifically `undefined`).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. Anyway upon reading the documentation for React.Children it came to my attention the **function** ***fn*** **(child) {** where  when invoking ***fn*** it is said that if the children is null or undefined it returns null or undefined, and as such saving me a lot of hassle!